# Installing and Running a project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Please bear with me as I am brand new to Java and Eclipse programming. I was looking around for some cool example projects to learn from, and I came across this:

http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php?topic=23775.0

It seemed very interesting, and I would love to see how it works on the inside. However, I am having a great deal of trouble compiling and running this project in my personal Eclipse workspace. So in short, how would I run this project in my own Eclipse workspace? Any help is appreciated for this issue. The words "thank you" do not get used nearly enough on this site, so I would like to thank you all for being a part of what makes this forum such a helpful place for beginners.

Comment: `great deal of trouble`, can you please elaborate what error you see when you try to import or create the project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to File -> New -> Java Project.  Give your project an arbitrary name.  Keep the defaults suggested and press "Finish".  Unzip your zip somewhere, then copy the "com" folder to the clip board and paste it into the "src" folder in your Eclipse project.  It should start to compile automatically when you do that.  Then in your package explorer view, expand the "src" folder and then "com.springworldgames.jcgmusic".  Select "SongCreatorApplication" and press the green "Run SongCreatorApplication" button in the menu at the top.  It should launch.

Answer (score 0):

Your link does not seem to be a repository, it has a [downloadable jar](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/104012548/jcgmusic/jcgmusic.jar).

Use [JD GUI](http://jd.benow.ca). Open the application, drag and drop your JAR file into it.

After take the code and import it into Eclipse.